# How to add image path in user profile using multer-gridfs-storage ,express, mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, gridfs

below is my file upload code

```
/** Setting up storage using multer-gridfs-storage */
    var storage = GridFsStorage({
        gfs : gfs,
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            var datetimestamp = Date.now();
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1]);
        },
        /** With gridfs we can store aditional meta-data along with the file */
        metadata: function(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, { originalname: file.originalname });
        },
        root: 'ctFiles' //root name for collection to store files into
    });

    var upload = multer({ //multer settings for single upload
        storage: storage
    }).single('file');

    /** API path that will upload the files */
    app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
        upload(req,res,function(err){
            if(err){
                 res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
                 return;
            }
            console.log(res.file);
            console.log(res[0].file);
             res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null});
        });
    });
```

i want to store user name, email and file path in user collection 
this is my UserSchema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true
    },
    filepath: String,
});
```

this is how image has stored in collection

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58fb894111387b23a0bf2ccc"),
        "filename" : "file-1492879681306.PNG",
        "contentType" : "image/png",
        "length" : 67794,
        "chunkSize" : 261120,
        "uploadDate" : ISODate("2017-04-22T16:48:01.350Z"),
        "aliases" : null,
        "metadata" : {
                "originalname" : "Front.PNG"
        },
        "md5" : "404787a5534d0479bd55b2793f2a74b5"
}
```

this is my expectation result: in user collection i should get data like this

```
{ 

        "name" :"asdf", 
        "email" : "asdf@gmail.com", 
        "filepath":"file/file-1492879681306.PNG"

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between storing in GridFS and storing in an ordinary MongoDb collection. The first is designed to efficiently **store files** with optionally any **additional information** while the later allows you to set **any schema** and store **any information**. You cannot deal with both the same way.

If what you want is to establish a relationship between a file and a schema in your application, you can do it like this.

1. Store the desired schema information in the metadata of the file

   Pro: All additional data is stored within the file and deleting the file automatically
   cleans the additional information.

   Con: Queries could become complex because all of them must be prefixed by a `metadata`
   field and all information is mixed together.

   This could be the output of one of your files

   ```
   {
       "_id" : ObjectId("58fb894111387b23a0bf2ccc"),
       "filename" : "file-1492879681306.PNG",
       "contentType" : "image/png",
       "length" : 67794,
       "chunkSize" : 261120,
       "uploadDate" : ISODate("2017-04-22T16:48:01.350Z"),
       "aliases" : null,
       "metadata" : {
           "originalname" : "Front.PNG",
           "name" :"asdf",
           "email" : "asdf@gmail.com",
           "filepath":"file/file-1492879681306.PNG"
       },
       "md5" : "404787a5534d0479bd55b2793f2a74b5"
   }
   ```

   Setting information like this is easy, just change the `metadata` function a little bit.

   ```
   ....
   /** With gridfs we can store aditional meta-data along with the file */
   metadata: function(req, file, cb) {
       var metadata = {
           originalname: file.originalname,
           // get this information somehow
           name :"asdf",
           email : "asdf@gmail.com",
           filepath:"file/file-1492879681306.PNG"
       };
       cb(null, metadata);
   },
   ....
   ```

   and this is how you should access them although you could use `db.collection` or `Mongoose` to the same purpose.

   ```
   const mongodb = require('mongodb');
   const GridFSBucket = mongodb.GridFSBucket;
   const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

   MongoClient.connect('mongodb://yourhost:27017/database').then((db) => {
       const bucket = new GridFSBucket(db, {bucketName: 'ctFiles'});

       bucket
           .find({metadata: {'email' : 'asdf@gmail.com'}})
           .toArray()
           .then((fileInfoArr) => {
               console.log(fileInfoArr);
           });
   });
   ```

   Then you can use the `fileInfo` array to create streams and read the file.
2. Store the schema independently and add an `ObjectId` field that points to the id of the stored file.

   Pro: Queries and updates over your UserSchema are easier to compose and understand because schema definitions are stored in different collections.

   Con: Now you have two collections to worry about and have to manually keep
   both in sync; when a file is deleted you should delete the User data and viceversa.

   This is how your `UserSchema` could look like

   ```
    var UserSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        email: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true
        },
        filepath: String,
        fileId: Schema.Types.ObjectId
   });
   ```

   and this is how you access the files

   ```
   UserModel.findOne({'email' : 'asdf@gmail.com'}, function (err, user) {
       // deal with error
       // store and get the db object somehow

       const bucket = new GridFSBucket(db, {bucketName: 'ctFiles'});

       // A download stream reads the file from GridFs
       const readStream = bucket.openDownloadStream(user.fileId));

       readStream.pipe(/* some writable stream */);
   });
   ```

Remember that GridFs stores files, therefore you should use streams whenever possible to read and write data handling [backpressure](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/) correctly.

PD:

Stuff like `root` belong to [`GridStore`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/GridStore.html) which is obsolete. You should use [`GridFSBucket`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/GridFSBucket.html) whenever possible. The new version of `multer-gridfs-storage` also deals with `bucketName` instead of `root`.